# Проблема с системой координат в turtle

Tags: python-3.x, turtle

У меня есть программа, которая при вводе в неё координат центра (по x и y) и радиуса двух кругов, вычисляет, пересекаются ли они. Я решил прикрутить к этой программе визуализацию с помощью turtle для наглядности, но проблема в том, что в итоге получается, что программа пишет, что круги пересекаются, но на рисунке в окне turtle круги находятся далеко друг от друга и вообще не соответствуют введённым координатам. Это происходит не всегда, иногда вердикт программы и рисунок совпадают.
Вот код:

```
import turtle
def check(x,y,r,x2,y2,r2):
    G = (r + r2) > (x - x2) and (r + r2) > (y2 - y)
    return G



def draw_circle1(x,y,r):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.circle(r)

def draw_circle2(x2,y2,r2):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x2,y2)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.circle(r2)

def main():
    turtle.setup (width=800, height=500, startx=600, starty=200)
    turtle.bgcolor('white')
    turtle.color('black')
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.hideturtle()
    s = input('Введите координаты центра первого круга по горизонтали, вертикали и его радус через пробел: ')
    s2 = input('Введите координаты центра второго круга по горизонтали, вертикали и его радус через пробел: ')
    x,y,r = s.split()
    x2,y2,r2 = s2.split()
    x = float(x)
    y = float(y)
    r = float(r)
    x2 = float(x2)
    y2 = float(y2)
    r2 = float(r2)
    draw_circle1(x,y,r)
    draw_circle2(x2,y2,r2)
    G = check(x,y,r,x2,y2,r2)
    if G:
        print('Круги пересекаются')
    else:
        print('Круги не пересекаются')
    turtle.mainloop()

main()
```

[image: Результат выполнения]

Подозреваю, что проблема в том, что черепаха рисует круг не из центра, а по своему алгоритму. Как сделать так, чтобы вердикт программы и рисунок совпадали?

P.S. Изучаю питон и в целом программирование от силы пару недель.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверка, что круги пересекаются, должна основываться на сравнении суммы радиусов и расстояния между центрами. Здесь используются квадраты этих величин:

```
def check(x,y,r,x2,y2,r2):
    G = (r + r2)**2 > (x - x2)**2 + (y2 - y)**2
    return G
```

Answer (score 0):

По поводу неверности отображения, координаты X и Y являются не точкой центра требуемой вами окружности, а координатой точки, откуда Turtle будет рисовать вашу окружность(по сути нижняя точка окружности), чтобы отрисовка была верной нужно вместо условной pos_y передавать (pos_y - radius)